# Fire off event after job-chain has "finished"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I have below Listener called `ProcessDocumentFields`. My listener class implements the `ShouldQueue`.

In this, I fire off two jobs by using the `withChain` method as below:

```php
ParseFieldContent::withChain([
        new ParseFieldRules($event->document, $fields),
])->dispatch($event->document, $fields);
```

Now, I want to conditionally fire off an event, which ultimately trigger another job.

The thing is, both jobs (`ParseFieldContent` and `ParseFieldRules`) must have finished running.

```php
#If below is true, fire off
if ($event->document->stream->settings()->get('field_routing')) {
   event(new DocumentDefaultRulesWasProcessed($event->documents));
}
```

The above event, will trigger the same two jobs, but I have to do some other checks first:

```php
#EventServiceProvider.php
DocumentDefaultRulesWasProcessed::class => [
     ProcessDocumentRouteFields::class,
],
```

Inside my `ProcessDocumentRouteFields`, I have:

```php
foreach ($event->routes as $route) {
        if ($this->assertIfRouteFieldsShouldBeHandled($route, $event->document)) {
            ParseFieldContent::withChain([
                new ParseFieldRules($event->document, $route->fields, false),
            ])->dispatch($event->document, $route->fields);
        }
}
```

As you can see in above, I run the two same jobs (`ParseFieldContent` and `ParseFieldRules`) - but only if a certain assertion is true.

My question is: how can I ensure, that the jobs placed in `ProcessDocumentFields` runs first, then when the `` event is being fired,  the jobs in `ProcessDocumentRouteFields` will run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On first thought, you could set some sort of indicator, either by caching or DB, which is used to check if the `ProcessDocumentFields` jobs are processing/running.

Then, in your `ProcessDocumentRouteFields`, you check to see if the job is still processing/running.

The cache method would look something like:

```
if (cache('processing_job')) {
    return;
}

foreach ($event->routes as $route) {
        if ($this->assertIfRouteFieldsShouldBeHandled($route, $event->document)) {
            ParseFieldContent::withChain([
                new ParseFieldRules($event->document, $route->fields, false),
            ])->dispatch($event->document, $route->fields);
        }
}
```

Please note that when caching, it must be set to enough time to execute the jobs.

```
cache('processing_job', true, now()->addMinutes(20));
```

You can then remove the key/value pair after all is completed (place at the end of job script):

```
Cache::forget('processing_job');
```

After this, the next time the cache check is performed, the cache helper will return false and process the other jobs.

I hope this helps.